# got a TAship award- is it a difficult task

Tags: graduate-school, teaching-assistant

i am awarded TAship to fund my phd studies although i know TA roles and responsibilities and actually quite excited to carry out these tasks but on the other hand i am dreading a little that what if i can't manage my duties along with my PhD studies and start doubting myself, which is wrong. so is it really tough that you can't manage it along with your coursework especially when you have never done this before? i would appreciate any advice from someone who have experience in TAing. Thanks

Comment: Congratulations! The word difficult is ill defined. I am sure you will enjoy your TA duty and your research...!!!

Comment: Is this in the US or elsewhere?

Comment: The answer to this is going to vary tremendously, not just within schools or departments, but by the professor you're assigned to TA for.  I've seen (and experienced) everything from professors dumping loads of work on you and being very stressful to work for, to professors who are supportive and ask only the minimum of you, so you can focus on your graduate work.

Comment: A lot also depends on the personality and attitude of the TA.  Some graduate students who aren't very sociable find working with students to be extremely difficult while other graduate students find it to be very enjoyable.  In some departments and institutions, TA's are busy for at least the nominal 20 hours per week as TA's while in other departments, the work load is often much less than the nominal 20 hours per week.

Comment: Ask your department/program about it.  The work varies.

Comment: @Buffy its US university

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having spent over 6 years in grad school TA'ing and teaching my own classes, I will say that you will enjoy it a lot. Teaching gives benefits that are more valuable than the funding it brings -- funding in itself is great, of course! I think one learns the best when they teach a subject. Having less time for your own work, you get much better in time management. Teaching also allows one to get experienced in public speaking, refine their skills in communicating knowledge, strategizing among many other positive things. So congratulations!